# Converting CamelCase to KebabCase in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have a LWC component with the name sM_MyComp. I am calling this component using Kebab Case
<c-s-m_my-comp> --- But this is throwing an error --- 'Failed to resolve module'. Would anyone know what is wrong in the kebab Case syntax?

Comment: Have you tried `<c-s-m_-my-comp>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two case stylings here. You should not use underscore `_` with camel case and so with the Kebab case. Also, you should strictly follow the `camelCase` while defining the component name. Mixing two case styles is not a good practice. You need to rename your component. Also looking at the name of your component, it is difficult to read at one glance.

While `<c-s-m_-my-comp>` does work as suggested by @Sergio but I would not recommend that.
I would have preferred something like `smMyComp` which would be converted to kebab case like `<c-sm-my-comp>`.

Comment: Yes, it does work, and yes, I would definitely avoid doing that. Also, long strings of uppercase letters is really obnoxious to work with.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! And yes long strings of uppercase letters are really a bummer when converted to kebab case, I have faced that issue when I was a beginner in LWC.

Comment: Yea <c-s-m_-my-comp>  did work. But our organization is going with naming Convention for all the components to be SM_<name> so that's why we have to name the LWC component this way.

Comment: @sfdc07 That's an unfortunate choice. The source code gets more annoying to read when you start down this path. I realize you don't necessarily have a say in the matter, but you should at least caution your peers and superiors against that specific pattern. `sm-` would still be consistent, but less annoying to deal with.

Comment: Okay, so if my component name is sM-MyComp , how would it render in kebab case, will there be 2 hyphens in Kebab Case?